# Does the order of constraints in a pred matter?

Tags: alloy

Does the order of constraints in this `pred` matter:

```
pred Example {
   A
   B
   C
}
```

`A`, `B`, `C` represent constraints.

Is that `pred` the same as this `pred`:

```
pred Example {
   B
   A
   C
}
```

Are the constraints in an if-then-else ordered? For example, is `ReadMemory` and `WriteMemory` ordered in this if-then-else:

```
pred Example {
    {
       ReadMemory
       WriteMemory
    } implies C else D
}
```

Here's the motivation for my question: Page 222 of [Software Abstractions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262017156) has, `This assertion says that if a read, write, load, and read are performed in that order, then ...`

The word "order" in that sentence caught my attention. Hence my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, order of constraints does not matter. In the example you mention

```
 assert LoadNotObservable {
   all c, c’, c“: CacheSystem, a1, a2: Addr, d1, d2, d3: Data | 
    {read [c, a2, d2]
     write [c, c’, a1, d1]
     load [c’, c”] 
     read [c“, a2, d3] 
} implies d3 = (a1 = a2 => d1 else d2) }
```

it's the parameters (c, c', c") that define the pre and post states for the transitions.

Comment: Ah! That makes sense. Thanks Daniel!